# Django "OR queries in **kwargs" for filtering

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have an existing **filter_kwargs used for "and" filtering, how do I insert the "or" queries? currently the supposed "OR" queries are treated as "and" query.

Here's my base code:

```
search_text = form_data.get("search_text", "").strip(" ")

filter_kwargs = {
    "is_active": True,
    "is_admin": False,
}


if search_text != "":
    // these are the supposed "OR" queries. how do I insert "OR" queries in kwargs?
    filter_kwargs['user__first_name__icontains'] = search_text
    filter_kwargs['user__last_name__icontains'] = search_text
    filter_kwargs['user__email__icontains'] = search_text


Profiles = Profile.object.filter(**filter_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the items in `Q` objects, and "fold" these with a logical or:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Profiles = Profile.object.filter(Q(**filter_kwargs, _connector=Q.OR))
```

It looks however that the first items should be treated as AND, you can do that by adding these at the filter level (not the `Q`-level):

```
filter_kwargs = {}
if search_text:
    filter_kwargs['user__first_name__icontains'] = search_text
    filter_kwargs['user__last_name__icontains'] = search_text
    filter_kwargs['user__email__icontains'] = search_text

Profiles = Profile.object.filter(
    Q(**filter_kwargs, _connector=Q.OR),
    is_active=True,
    is_admin=False
)
```

Comment: He has `is_active` and `is_admin` here. Not sure he'd like to use those options as `OR`

Comment: @asiniy: edited with the option to use and logic with `is_active` and `is_admin`. Thanks.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Sir is there anyway I can retain the dynamism of the filter_kwargs? Since I would be putting dynamic "and" & "or" filters along the way. e.g: if min_age != "": filter_kwargs['age_gte'] = min_age.. and other more.. Thank for the answer above tho :)

Comment: @Christopher: but you still have the dynamism, I think. You can add any filter to the `filter_kwargs` that should be used with OR logic. The and logic is simply added here as kwargs. But you can not expect that the dictionary "knows" how to combine elements you add.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. Yes sir. My concern now is with "and" queries. Since the previously used for "and" kwargs is now used for "or". Would it still be dynamic sir? Or is it okay to have 2 kwargs like objects.filter(**or_kwargs, **and_kwargs)? since my goal is to have both "and" and "or" to retain its dynamism.

Comment: @Christopher: you can use `.filter(Q(**or_kwargs, _connector=Q.OR), **and_kwargs)`. It will create a query `(a OR b OR c) AND d AND e AND f` given `a`, `b` and `c` are in `or_kwargs`, and `d`, `e` and `f` are in `and_kwargs`.